# UItableView: Nested Header sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Here, I had set description, price as well as location from-to, but not able to set the date and time as shown in figure above. Format facing some issue to set the date in one header and time in another accordingly. If any link which shows how to set nested headers would help me a lot.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Are you struggling to add header with date and time in 2 lines with some separator in between as shown in image ?

Comment: yes.As shown in figure m not able to add a separator in between.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as shown in figure not able to add a separator in between.I also tried this

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
NSMutableArray *arrdate=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
arrdate=[date1 objectAtIndex:section] ;
NSLog(@"%@",arrdate);
NSMutableArray *arrtime=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
arrtime=[time objectAtIndex:section];
NSString *strvalue=[arrdate objectAtIndex:0];
UIView *view;

if([strvalue isEqualToString: strcheck])
{
    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 15)];
    /* Create custom view to display section header... */
    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width, 15)];
    [label1 setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    strcheck=[arrdate objectAtIndex:0] ;
    NSString *string =[arrtime objectAtIndex:0];
    /* Section header is in 0th index... */
    [label1 setText:string];
    [view addSubview:label1];

}
else{
    /* Create custom view to display section header... */
    view= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 100)];
    //main time
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, tableView.frame.size.width, 15)];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
    strcheck=[arrdate objectAtIndex:0] ;
    /* Section header is in 0th index... */
    [label setText:strcheck];
    [view addSubview:label];


    //time..
    UILabel *labeltime = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,20, tableView.frame.size.width, 15)];
    [labeltime setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];

    NSString *stringtime =[arrtime objectAtIndex:0];
    /* Section header is in 0th index... */
    [labeltime setText:stringtime];
    [view addSubview:labeltime];
    }
return view;
```

}

but facing problem that date view is getting disturb while scrolling tableview.

Answer (score -1):

Create a xib file which has a `UIView` and labels inside that as shown in the attached screenshot.
[image: xib with seperator]

1. Have a source files named `CustomHeader` which is subclass of `UIView`.
2. Map your xib view with `CustomHeader` class.
3. Generate `IBOutlets` for the labels added in xib.

In your `ViewController` `viewForHeaderInSection` method,

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSArray * bundleArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:nil];
CustomUIClass * view = (CustomUIClass *) [bundleArray objectAtIndex:0];
return view;
```

}

Also override `heightForHeaderInSection`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 69.0f;
```

}

here '69' is the height of the xib. Now your tableview looks like as attached screenshot.

[image: Customized tableview header]

Like this you can customise your header as per your requirement.